# Using AdobeTypeKit font in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community-builder

Can we use AdobeTypekit fonts in Lightning Components??

Thanks in Advance
Bala

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? is it possible or not ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you can upload font as static resource, create css rules to use this font and include static resource in aura

I did not try with fonts, but I have been working with custom css as static resource in lightning

This is for including resource in aura:

```
<ltng:require styles="/PATH_TO_RESOURCE" />
```